# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions, HttpClient to https

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, dotnet-httpclient

When I'm trying access API from another API getting this issue, giving below code sample that I given:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AKey", "123456");
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.testurl.com:88/api/GetSyncSupplierMaster"))
    {
        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        SupplierMaster = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SupplierMasterCls>>(apiResponse);
        for (int i = 0; i < SupplierMaster.Count; i++)
        {
            var SupDetail = (from b in _context.SupplierMasterCls
                        where b.ErpId.Equals(SupplierMaster[i].ErpId)
                        select b).ToList<GeAppSupplierMaster>();
            if (SupDetail.Count == 0)
            {
                InsertedSupplierCount = InsertedSupplierCount + 1;
                _context.SupplierMasterCls.Add(SupplierMaster[i]);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read this article: [You're using HttpClient wrong ...](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and avoid `using` around `HttpClient`.

Comment: Hi Mr. @PeterCsala, thank you for your time. actually I tried with same the you mentioned. but output is same error, **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013)**

Comment: Could you please amend your question and include the exception with all of its details?

Comment: @PeterCsala sure, EnqApp.Controllers.SupplierMasterController.GetandSetSupplierMaster() in C:\\Users\\SupplierMasterController.cs:line 170\nSystem.Net.Http\nSystem.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.   || 170th line is :- `var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.testurl.com:88/api/GetSyncSupplierMaster");`